# What resources, outside of the Microsoft site(s), are available for learning about Form and MVC web applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, winforms, webforms

I've found a few pages (some that even link to a number of other pages) on the Microsoft website that I bookmarked last night for reading today, but I'm curious as to other good non-Microsoft resources for discussing ASP.NET web applications, both Forms and MVC (including comparisons/contrasts between the two).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your eye out on the MVC forums, read up on blogs:

- [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com)
- [Scott Hanselman](http://computerzen.com)
- [Rob Conery](http://blog.wekeroad.com)
- [Simone Chiarretta](http://codeclimber.net.nz/)
- [Derik Whittaker](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker)
- [Me](http://flux88.com) :)
- [Jeremy Skinner](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/)
- [Torkel Odegaard](http://www.codinginstinct.com/)
- [Steve Sanderson](http://blog.codeville.net)

There's a ton of people blogging about it.  Also, check out some of the open source projects that are using it:

- [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.org)
- [Code Camp Server](http://codecampserver.org)
- [Kigg](http://www.codeplex.com/Kigg)

There's a bunch of books coming out:

- [Pro ASP.NET MVC](http://apress.com/book/view/1430210079) by Steve Sanderson
- [Programming ASP.NET MVC](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521851/) by Alex Horovitz
- [Beginning ASP.NET MVC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047043399X) by Simone Chiaretta
- [Professional ASP.NET MVC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470384611) by Phil Haack, Scott Hanselman, Rob Conery
- [ASP.NET MVC in Action](http://manning.com/palermo) by myself, Jeffrey Palermo, and Jimmy Bogard

> I think you can guess which one I
>   recommend most :).  Our book has an
>   early access program that allows you
>   to download PDFs as they're written.

```
</shamelessPlug>
```

Any thing else I should add to this list?  I'm marked it as community wiki.

Comment: Shameless promotion there, Ben! That said, I just bought it, so the advertisement worked!

Answer (score 2):

As a first port of call, I would use a social bookmarking network site, such as Delicious, to get a list of popular/tagged posts and sites:

- [ASP.NET MVC tagged bookmarks](http://delicious.com/tag/aspnetmvc)
- [Popular ASP.NET MVC bookmarks](http://delicious.com/popular/aspnetmvc)

Answer (score 1):

[Phil Haack's blog](http://haacked.com/) seems to be a good source. He's an insider and can tell you the tricks there are to know. In the end it all depends on how you prefer to learn - some people like videos, others prefer books. For me the best way is to learn by doing it. So take a look at Phil, go to CodePlex and find a project that uses ASP.NET MVC and look at the code. That way you'll also see how people solved their problems and what practices they followed, not only learn the rules of the framework.